# Swift compilation: Variable 'self.anInt' used before being initialized - any ideas why?

Tags: swift

I'm working on a large project where a compilation error has suddenly and unexpectedly surfaced. It's weird because it's spread across two completely separate pieces of code, one which triggers the error, and the other where the error appears.

Since it's impractical to copy the code into SOF, I've managed to distill it down to the following which exhibits the same compiler error in a playground:

```swift
struct AppConfiguration {
    // Won't compile until this is commented out - ???
    let x = Measurement<UnitMass>(value: 1.0, unit: .kilograms)
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @State var anInt: Int
    // Or THIS is commented out - ???
    let config = AppConfiguration()
    init() {
        anInt = 5   // Compilation error: Variable 'self.anInt' used before being initialized
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello \(anInt)")
    }
}
```

In it we have two types. `AppConfiguration` which has the `x:Measurement<UnitMass>` value and `SomeView` which has a reference to the config.

*Please ignore all the coding issues like the fact that I'm setting the `State` variable in the `init()` and that I'm no actually using `config`. As I said this is the simplest bit of code that exhibits the bug and it the original code these things are there for other reasons which are irrelevant to this issue.*

Now when I run this in a playground I get the error **`Variable 'self.anInt' used before being initialized`** in the `init()` where `anInt = 5`.

Which makes no sense as this code has been fine for weeks. But yesterday we added the `let x = Measurement...` line to the `AppConfiguration` and now we get this error.

- If I change the type of `x` in `AppConfiguration` to a `Double` the error on the init goes away.
- If I remove the config from `SomeView` and break the dependency the error also goes away.
- Or if I remove `x` from `AppConfiguration` it also goes away.

All of which makes no sense.

Why would using the `Measurement` type in the `AppConfiguration` trigger a compilation error on a line of code in a different type that has nothing to do with it?

Can any one explain why `Measurement` is breaking compilation in this way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's weird. But I found thing that make sense on your case.
`Measurement` type conforms to `ReferenceConvertible` protocol. There're some types such as:

```
AffineTransform
Calendar
CharacterSet
Data
Date
DateComponents
DateInterval
INMediaDestination
INShortcut
IndexPath
IndexSet
Locale
Measurement
Notification
PersonNameComponents
TimeZone
URL
URLComponents
URLQueryItem
URLRequest
UTType
UUID
```

will fall to same error.
I think the compiler need to do something related to `@State` modifier.
It's recommended to set it's default value or use underlying property `_anInt`

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var anInt: Int
    let date = Date()
    
    init() {
        _anInt = State(initialValue: 5) // no error
        // anInt = 5 -> compile error
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/referenceconvertible/

Comment: I think you're onto something here. It feels like the compiler is having some issue and giving out an error that's miss-representing the problem. Certainly according to a number of posts I read initialising a @State variable in an init is quite doable. I'm going to report it.

Answer (score 0):

`anInt` is of type `State<Int>`, so you need to initialise it with this type.
The `@State` wrapper does it for you, but when you do it yourself, like in `init()`
you need to use `_anInt`.

Try this:

```
init() { 
    _anInt = State(initialValue: 5) 
}
```

This is the full code I used to show my answer works.

You can also remove the `init()` and use `@State var anInt: Int = 5`.

```
struct AppConfiguration {
    let x = Measurement<UnitMass>(value: 1.0, unit: .kilograms)
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @State var anInt: Int
    let config = AppConfiguration()
    
    init() {
        _anInt = State(initialValue: 5)  // <-- here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello \(anInt)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be the same as initialize value right?

Comment: yes, same as `@State var anInt: Int = 5`, and no `init()`

Comment: Yes we changed the code to using _anInt = State(... in the initialiser. It got it compiling again, but according to a number of posts I've read doing what we did is now fine and as I said the code was quite happy until we added Measurement. I think @Quang Ha's answer is possibly on the money in terms of a possible explanation for why the compile is getting it wrong.